# I want to call one ionic 3 event/method once user scans barcode through scanning machine without using click action

Tags: ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

Using below code as in plugin documentation-

```
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
     console.log('Barcode data', barcodeData);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error', err);
    });

 Should call scan() without using button for click i.e. directly when user scans product, we should get barcode in this method.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation?

> The Barcode Scanner Plugin opens a camera view and automatically scans
>   a barcode, returning the data back to you.

As I do also use some laserscanners and get the direct input you have some options here:

1) Create a hidden input field, get the button activity, once pressed focus the hidden input and paste the value inside, afterwards work with that value.
- Problem here is, that the keyboard will be opened and you have to hide it again but it will mostly be shown for a few ms. It's also not that precise because you have to define a timer after which the value will be read, therefore it will always take e.g. 300ms.

2) See if there are plugins out there which work via intent activity to receive your data. There are plugins for zebra and honeywell scanners.

Comment: Thanx for quick reply